# Как распарсить массив?

Tags: json, парсер, android

Привет всем. Помогите, пожалуйста! Есть массив вида:

```
[
 {
   "title":"title_name",
   "picture":"link_picture",
   "href":"href_",
   "date":"date",
 }
]
```

Не могу понять, как его распарсить?! Как парсить с ключом, понятно, а такой не понимаю, и в нете мало инфы. Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: > в нете мало инфи

Ну зачем врать-то? На одном только ХэшКоде этот вопрос поднимался не один десяток раз. Скажите честно, что вам лень искать и разбираться.

Comment: Чесно, конкретно по такому примеру не видел. Или я слепой. Если не сложно, подскажите или кодом, или ссылкой)

Comment: @Alerx, плохо искали http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но я все рано не понял ничего) Ладно, буду шерстить дальше...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSON самый простой вариант, но если всё совсем плохо, вот вариант в лоб:

```
String json = Ваш JSON
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
   if (array != null){
     for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
       JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
       if (jsonObject != null){
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title_name");
            String picture = jsonObject.getString("link_picture");
            String href = jsonObject.getString("href_");
            String date = jsonObject.getString("date");
  }
 }
```

}

Для ознакомления, делать это в проекте крайне не рекомендую.

Comment: Ну, в общем, я так и сделал уже )) спасибо огрномное.   
Пользуясь моментом, еще вопросик) Все эти данные я вывожу в Listview, поле Titile на русском языке - как вы, наверное, догадались, вывод - кракозяблики)  
Что делать, подскажите.

Comment: Дело в кодировке, как вариант попробуйте:
 
`String utf8Title= new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");`

или погуглите на эту тему.

Comment: Не помогло. И файлы сохранял в utf-8 без BOM, тоже 0 эффекта, только краказяблы на другие краказяблы меняються...))

Answer (score 4):

Используйте GSON, и будет все просто:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourCustomObject[] data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourCustomObject[].class);
```

Comment: Прикольно советовать GSON человеку, который не знает, как распарсить строку в JSONobject :)  

-------------

Связанные вопросы >>>>>>>>>>

Comment: А подробней можно? )

Comment: @Alerx, 
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide